# Membership Built In System

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I need to have a login area with the ability to add users to groups in my project.

The built in membership account that come with MVC is just what I need, although I've seen on blogs that some people warn against using the built in system and that you should delete it.

I'm new to mvc and .net so the likely hood of me writing something from scratch thats better is un likely at this stage.

Have other people used the built in system or are there any better alternative i should be looking at?

Thanks for any advice.

Jemes

Answer (score 0):

It'll work out of the box for simple cases - it's built directly on the ASP.NET 2.0 Membership ([read all about it here](https://web.archive.org/web/20211020202857/http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/120705-1.aspx)) and has the same limitations.  There's an open source project called [ASP.Net Membership](http://mvcmembership.codeplex.com/) which adds some actions/views for the administration bits.